Using vim plugin, how do you change font size?
I would like to change the font size of code blocks in a document.  I am using the vim plugin and a define macro in my environment file:
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[go][
  syntax=go,
  strip=yes,
  tab=4,
  fontsize=9pt, % doesn't have any effect
]


I never used that module, but could it be that style=\switchtobodyfont[9pt] or style=\ttx or something similar works to change the font?

The fontsize key doesn't exist for any ConTeXt commands, but you can instead use the style key with an appropriate sizing command:
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[go][
    syntax=go,
    strip=yes,
    tab=4,
    style=\ttx,  %% Best if you just want something smaller
    % style={\setupbodyfont[tt,9pt]},  %% Required if you want an exact font size
]

\startbuffer[go]
    func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
    }
\stopbuffer

\startTEXpage[offset=1ex]
    \typebuffer[go]
    \processgobuffer[go]
\stopTEXpage


